# In PHP how can I retrieve file from mysql database and send as attachment in email?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmailer

After figuring out PhpMailer now I have been concentrating on how to move files out of the database and append as attachment to an email. On the phpMailer site it is stated that an attachment must have 4 specifics in order to be attached, that is: $mail->addAttachment($path, $name, $encoding, $type); I Have 3 of these but know from downloading from my database that I don't have a $path. I thought of the potential for moving my file from my database to a temporary location, and then upload as an attachment but, I can't find anything on this. I have the ability to download my file from the database. I have included that code below.

Here is the code from my PHPMailer file:

```
m->isHTML(true);
//adding file to be attached
$m->addAttachment($path, $name, $encoding, $type);

$m->Subject = "Here is an Email";
$m->Body = "<p>This is the body of the email</p><br><strong>Test for 
HTML formatting</strong><br>";
$m->AltBody = "This is the body of an email";
$m->send();
echo "message has been sent";
```

Here is the code from my file download file.

```
$filename = $rows['name'];
$filesize = $rows['filesize'];
$content =  $rows['wholeMP3'];
$type = $rows['type']; 

header("Content-length: $filesize");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
ob_clean();
flush();
echo $content;
$LastProduct->closeCursor();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you dont need to save to a file, you can use a string:

```
AddStringAttachment($string,$filename,$encoding,$type)
```

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial

Comment: Thanks. I didn't look into that because thought it wasn't relevant but its just what I need.

Comment: What does $string correspond to?

Comment: did you read the tutorial link? or maybe even: http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_addStringAttachment or even the source https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/da9fede584e200038ae78e7cd153d092a210f9b7/src/PHPMailer.php#L3238 its just php after all